# Could you please correct me Passive voice error in word blue line

Tags: passive-voice

Responsible for the provision, care and management of permanent collections of information that "are intended" to preserve the past and allow others to discover it.

Comment: Do you mean that the Word program underlined something in blue, indicating a grammatical error? If so, what alternative did the grammar checker suggest? Proofreading questions are off-topic here.

Comment: It looks to me like Word was making a suggestion rather than indicating an error. It highlights the passive voice because many authors use it inappropriately, but this usage looks fine.

Comment: I expect MS Word is biased towards checking ***sentences***. But the cited text isn't a sentence. It isn't even a *clause*, since it doesn't include both a subject and predicate, so there's probably no point in wondering what Word makes of it, or why.

Answer (score 1):

> Responsible for the provision, care and management of permanent collections of information that "are intended" to preserve the past and allow others to discover it.

This is not a clause, but an adjectival phrase.  It should hence not start with a capital letter and end with a full stop.

The phrase *permanent **collections** of **information** that "are intended"* could have led the word processor to interpret the subject-verb pair as **information-are**, which obviously is detected as an error.

From the context, having **collections-are** as the subject-verb pair is possible.